# Creating traffic intersection polygon from arc endpoints in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, geometry, topology

I am trying to make a polygon of the boundaries of traffic intersections using a python script. I want to automatically create intersection polygons made of arcs and lines connecting them. Essentially, what I need to create are lines labeled in red below to finish off the polygon.

How do I make the script "know" which two arc endpoints to connect to make the red lines? If I create a line between each point and its nearest neighbor, it could mess up if one road is wider than the other. Also, how could I make the line extend perpendicularly from the ac endpoint until it hits the other end of the intersection? [image]

Comment: Are there road name attributes?  Road A could be going East-West, and Road B could be North South.  Then, you could use the name of Road A and B to link them.  You know the end points of Road A need to match with Road B.  Alternatively, you could get the endpoint coordinates and sort them clockwise, for example.  Then connect them in order.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approximation assuming that you have individual lines representing your roads:

1. Buffer your road lines
2. Intersect the buffered polygons[image]

The result should look approximately similar to the picture below: